# Yii Behaviors and scenario

Tags: yii, behavior

i have a behavior for my models, the behavior has beforeFind, beforeSave, in methods i override user_id, something like:

```
...
public functio beforeSave() {
  $this->owner->user_id = Yii::app()->user->id
}
```

I have model User, how can i disable behavior for registration new user?
Saving code:

```
$user = new User();
$user->id = 1332;
$user->field1 = 'data';
$user->save();
```

but on save i have null in $user->id (because work behavior).
 i tried

```
$user->disableBehaviors(); 
$user->detachBehavior();
```

Without result.

Maybe its not right way? I create behaviors for identify users in system (find only user something, save only with user id...), but that if i have new user with full previegies, i should again detach behaviors?

Answer (score 1):

If condition can be changed in future I just pass it as callback parameter into behavior from model.

This give you a bit more control over the condition. Hence, behavior becomes more reusable - if it is used by several models this condition can be unique for each.

Example below is a bit simplified, but you should get the idea.

Behavior:

```
class SomeBehavior extends CActiveRecordBehavior
{
    public $trigger;

    public function beforeSave($event)
    {
        if(!call_user_func($this->trigger))
            return;

        // do what you need
        $this->owner->user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;

    }
}
```

Model:

```
class SomeModel extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        $me=$this;

        return array(
            'some'=>array(
                'class'=>'SomeBehavior',
                'trigger'=>function() use($me){
                    return $me->scenario=='some-scenario';
                }
            )
        );

    }
}
```

Also I use PHP 5.3. So, I use closure for `trigger` callback.
If your PHP version is less than 5.3 - anything callable can be used instead. Check here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php

Answer (score 1):

Because of behavior is a method, you can declare your own logic inside.

The model knows about its scenario, so there is no problem to return different arrays for different conditions:)

Hope it be helpful for somebody.

Answer (score 0):

You can check Yii::app()-user->isGuest to determine if the user is logged in or not.  or you can just try looking for the null.  Like this:

```
if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) 
    $this->owner->user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
```

or

```
if (null !== Yii::app()->user->id)
    $this->owner->user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
```

Comment: Looked not a universal, what if i will have new role - administrator, i should write new check if is it administrator..

Comment: I keep audit fields in every model that record the create user name and timestamp, and also the change user and timestamp every time a record is created or changed.  Instead of writing the code to populate these audit fields in every model, I wrote an event handler and attached it to the onBeforeSave event in each model in the init() function.  To determine if the record was being created I used $model->isNewRecord.  Model comes fromthe event that is passed in to the handler.